# Get git SHA-1 of code merged by jenkins into maven

Tags: git, jenkins, maven-3, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I am using the "Merge before build" option of the git plugin to build a maven job.  I have tried using ${GIT_BRANCH} and ${GIT_COMMIT} in my maven pom to write the commit information into my built artifacts but these variable are set to the branch being merged and its commit SHA-1.

Is there a way that I can find the SHA-1 of merged code and pass it into maven?

Comment: I can add a pre-build step to run a shell and execute `cd $WORKSPACE; export GIT_MERGE_COMMIT=`git rev-parse HEAD`` which gets the SHA-1 into the environment variable `GIT_MERGE_COMMIT` but there down't seem to be any good way to get this [into the maven goal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627144/using-a-variable-obtained-using-a-pre-build-shell-command-to-set-an-option-for-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mojo's Buildnumber Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) can fetch this information for you.

The project site has not been fully updated to reflect the fact that it works with GIT.

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>create</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <doCheck>true</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

That will set the `${buildNumber}` property to the full GIT hash of your workspace.

It also will have the side-effect of ensuring that the build is the same on either a developers machine or the CI build server.

Comment: Thanks, the plugin lets me get the hash I want.  For anyone else trying this, note that you need to configure the `maven-scm-plugin` in your pom before the buildnumber plugin can get the hash information

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [maven git commit id plugin](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin). It will provide you with a lot of information from Git, it supports fancy formatting and many different use cases.

[Direct link to the documentation](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin#using-the-plugin).